# Closed questions and Area 51 site stats

Tags: support, area-51, beta-sites

Are **closed questions** counted in the *unanswered questions* stats in Area 51, or are they just left out of the stats completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closed questions are not counted.

On [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) for example, there are ~100 [questions with no answers](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0) (all closed). There are ~2,600 total questions. Doing the math, that means that *if we take closed questions into account*, 3.8% of questions have no answers. However, their stats say [100% answered](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills), so closed questions are not counted for this.